# How do I handle errors in a function called from a route handler in Express, NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, express, error-handling

This may be extremely stupid, but I haven't found much about this because I don't understand how I should search this.

I have a route handler that may call different functions depending on some request parameters, and I would like to know what's the best way to deal with errors inside the functions in order to pass errors to the error handling middleware.
Consider something like this:

```
router.get('/error/:error_id', (req, res, next) => {
    my_function();
}

function my_function(){
  // do something async, like readfile
  var f = fs.readFile("blablabla", function (err, data) {
      // would want to deal with the error
  });
}
```

If an error occurs during `fs.readFile`, how do I pass the error to `next` to forward it to the error middleware? The only solution is to pass the next param to the function function `my_function(next){...}`?

In case the function didn't call any async I/O operation, a simple `try/catch` in the route handler would be ok (i suppose), like this:

```
router.get('/error/:error_id', (req, res, next) => {
    try{
      my_function();
    } catch(e){
      next(e);
    };
}

function my_function(){
  // do stuff
  var f = fs.readFileSync("blablabla"); // possibly throws an error
}
```

Hope I make some sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are totally correct that you should pass the `next` callback to `my_function` since `fs.readFile` is asynchronous.

```
router.get('/error/:error_id', (req, res, next) => {
  my_function(next);
}

function my_function(next) {
  fs.readFile("blablabla", function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      next(err);
    } else {
      // Process the data
      // Don't forget to call `next` to send respond the client
    }
  });
}
```

By the way, you cannot do

```
var f = fs.readFile(...)
```

because `fs.readFile` is asynchronous. The data should be handled within the callback.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of errors can be occured in our server. So try catch block can handle  Synchronous errors.

```
    try {
          my_function();
        }
    catch(e){
        };
```

But for asynchronous errors

```
 try {
      my_function();
    }
 catch(e){
      next(e);
    };
```

also you chan use .then() instead of try catch

```
Promise.resolve().then(() => {
    throw new Error('BROKEN')
  }).catch(next)
```

documentation - [Express error handling](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html)

you can use  express-async-handler for handle this very easy [express-async-handler](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-async-handler)